# If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-icons

I'm clueless about an error message that keeps coming back. I'm transforming my existing Vue2 codebase to Vue3. I'm also ditching the existing icon package as it is incompatible with Vue 2. Instead I'm now using https://github.com/tommyip/bootstrap-icons-vue

When properly configured, I get the following error message:

```
*[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: b-icon-heart-fill
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Sidebar onModal=fn<bound modalClick> > 
  at <AsyncComponentWrapper onModal=fn<bound modalClick> > 
  at <App>*
```

I using the following (simplified) template code:

```
<template>
  <b-icon-heart-fill />
</template>
```

And this for the Vue code:

```
// Importing all icons
import { BIconHeartFill } from 'bootstrap-icons-vue';
export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
    BIconHeartFill,
    BIconCheckCircleFill,
    BIconFire,
    BIconStarFill
  }
}
```

Any idea what goes wrong here?